# How to make a dynamic button to book training

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm creating an application where an user can book training. I want this application to let the user book once per day, not more.

I'm trying to create a method in the User model that is called `not_booked?` and if the argument is true then let the user book, else unbook.

This is not working in my application and I would like to know why, and how to fix it.

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trainings, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

    def not_booked?(booked)
      booked = self.bookings(@training)
      booked = true
    end
     .
     .
     .

end
```

Training show view:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.left_slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>

    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
    </center>
```

And the booking_form.html.erb view is:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
      <% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %>
      <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% else %>
        <% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
    <%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(booking.training, booking), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you certain you want to delete this?' }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I do the reserve, if I try to do it again I can, but I don't want the user to do more than one book.

Maybe I don't know how to set the booking status to true for the user. I would like to know how I can do it.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the parts relevant for the question. The rest is just distracting.

Comment: done! edited! and sorry.

Comment: Your current implementation of the `not_booked?` does nothing but return true. Whatever it is that you are passing into the `not_booked?` method is referenced as `booking`, however you then proceed to immediately assign a local variable of the same name and thereby the argument you have passed into the method is no longer accessible to you.
Also, where does `@training` come from in the model? Is that maybe what you wanted to pass in as an argument?

Comment: I was trying to refer to something like if user is booked in @training show this. Now that you say that i know its not good how im doing it. Do you have any ideas how i could get this idea done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `not_booked?` method should probably look like this:

```
def not_booked?(training)
  bookings.where(training_id: training.id).none?
end
```

Read this as

> A training `t` is not booked by a user `u` if among all bookings of `u` there is no booking `b` with `b.training_id == t.id`

Comment: did not work.. still appearing the book option when user already has one

Comment: Then some assumptions I made do not hold, e.g., it could be that either booking or training are not persisted? Or I've misunderstood your question..? I've explained in words what the above method does.